# Updating Azure DevOps Library insert Key Vault Variable with Azure DevOps API

Tags: api, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

I'm using the Azure DevOps API for maintaining the variable inside the library of Azure DevOps.
For the secret and non secret variables I can use the Azure DevOps REST API to perform the standard maintenance actions (Get/Insert/Update/Delete).

But now i've added a library where i make use of the secrets from Azure Key Vault.
Picture of Library configuration [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVJRc.png)

With this configured it is possible to retrieve the normal variables as well as the variable linked with secret server. I use the following call: [https://dev.azure.com/{organisation}/{account}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/10?api-version=5.1-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganisation%7D/%7Baccount%7D/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/10?api-version=5.1-preview.1)

But when i want to update the variables with secrets from Azure KeyVault that is not possible.
I se use the POST action with URI: [https://dev.azure.com/{organisation}/{account}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/10?api-version=5.1-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganisation%7D/%7Baccount%7D/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/10?api-version=5.1-preview.1)

with the following json:

```
{
  "count":1,
  "value":[
    {
      "variables":{
        "dummy":{
          "enabled":true,
          "contentType":"",
          "value":null,
          "isSecret":true
        },
        "AKV-Test":{
          "enabled":true,
          "contentType":"",
          "value":null,
          "isSecret":true
        }
      },
      "id":10,
      "type":"AzureKeyVault",
      "name":"{libraryname}",
      "description":"",
      "providerData":{
        "serviceEndpointId":"{endpoint}",
        "vault":"{keyvault}",
        "lastRefreshedOn":"2022-03-16T08:38:18.201Z"
      },
      "createdBy":{
        "displayName":"{displayName}",
        "id":"{id}",
        "uniqueName":"{uniqueName}"
      },
      "createdOn":"2021-12-10T06:52:53.0666667Z",
      "modifiedBy":{
        "displayName":"{displayName}",
        "id":"{id}",
        "uniqueName":"{uniqueName}"
      },
      "modifiedOn":"2022-03-16T14:37:05.8866667Z",
      "isShared":false,
      "variableGroupProjectReferences":null
    }]
}
```

The Key Vault is connected because inside this library I can manually add the Secret and save the library. But when i perform the same action with the REST Api i get the following error:

```
 {
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: group.Name",
    "typeName": "System.ArgumentNullException, mscorlib",
    "typeKey": "ArgumentNullException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 0
    }
```

Does anybody has an idea what i'm doing wrong or is the expected solution with the REST Api not possible?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can use Powershell for builds. You can create a [service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) from your project to Azure Subscription and then use this task:

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: InlineScript'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '<SUBSCRIPTION_CONNECTION_NAME>'
    ScriptType: InlineScript
    Inline: |
     # You can write your azure powershell scripts inline here. 
     # You can also pass predefined and custom variables to this script using arguments
     
     $secretvalue = ConvertTo-SecureString "<PASSWORD>" -AsPlainText -Force
     $secret = Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "<AKV_NAME>" -Name "<SECRETE_NAME>" -SecretValue $secretvalue
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
```

Check this link: [Quickstart: Set and retrieve a secret from Azure Key Vault using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-powershell)

Comment: Hi Shamrai Aleksander,
Thanks for the information but this is not exactly what i want because i want to have the library inside Azure DevOps correct and your proposal is to change my build strategy.